# try_files in nginx.conf not working

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm working with an angular 2 app, nginx and docker. Everytime I'm reloading a page with /site it gives me a 404. My server block looks like this right now:

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/project/html;

index index.html;

server_name project.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}}
```

I have tried a lot, and have seen ALL other stackoverflow questions and have tried every possibility. But nothing works. Can someone please help?

UPDATE:
The whole nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

the sites-enabled/default:

```
    server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/project/html;

index index.html;

server_name project.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}}
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./docker/sites-enabled /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./dist /var/www/project/html
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: do you have any error logs?

Comment: @Moema there is just the error log: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. Nothing else.

Comment: I mean the Nginx error log which you can configure in your nginx.conf (see https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) I think per default they are located at /var/log/nginx/

Comment: I had to open the log in my docker, but it doesn't open. Even vim says, that error.log is not a file

Comment: so your server block looks definitely right (presuming that your index.html is located at /var/www/project/html) - maybe it's a issue with your docker setup. Can you post the whole nginx.conf and your dockerfile?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: how do you access your site? At project.com? What I can see is that you load configs from `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` - Nginx usually comes with a default config in that directory, maybe that is messing up something

Comment: You say everytime you *reload* you get 404. Do you ever get the page? Also, are you really using 0.0.0.0?

Comment: What does the nginx logs say. Also what is the output of `nginx -T`?

Comment: @Moema right now I am accessing the site just with localhost. Where should I load than the configs from?

Comment: @Rob, if I go to localhost I can click on buttons and it's routing normally. After one route I reload it and it shows a 404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your nginx.conf, you are loading additional configs from two locations:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

The second one loads your `sites.enabled/default` config with the server name `project.com`.

The first one, though, loads the default config `default.conf` which is part of the nginx docker image per default. That config looks similar to

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    ....

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    ....
}
```

So if you try to access your site with `localhost`, your `sites-enabled/default` is never used (since you specified the server_name `project.com` and that doesn't match with `localhost`). Instead the request runs in the `default.conf` since there the server_name is `localhost`.

And in the `default.conf` the location part is:

```
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

That means, if you just go to `localhost`, the `index.html` is served and everything works as expected. But as soon as you try accessing `localhost/something`, Nginx is trying to find the file/directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/something` which doesn't exist (-> 404).

So you have to options:

1. Remove `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` from your nginx.conf (or delete the `default.conf`) and change the server_name in your `sites-enabled/default` to `localhost`. Then your request will run into your config.
2. Add the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` to the location in the `default.conf` like you have it in your `sites-enabled/default`.

I would recommend the first solution, do not include the `default.conf` and change your `server_name` to `localhost` in your `sites-enabled/config`. If you later need your real domain, you can still use regex to match for either localhost or your domain.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You are my life-saver

Comment: This is a perfect explanation.

Comment: perfect, very interesting illustration :), that's helped me !

Comment: this is not working     server {
   listen 0.0.0.0:80;
   listen [::]:80;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip                    on;
  gzip_comp_level         6;
  gzip_vary               on;
   gzip_min_length         1000;
   gzip_proxied            any;
   gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
   gzip_buffers            16 8k;
   client_max_body_size    256M;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   location / {   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}